# Why aren't there HiRISE observation footprints near the Martian poles?

Tags: mars, mars-reconnaissance-orbiter, hirise

Browsing the [HiRISE observations](https://www.uahirise.org/hiwish/browse) of Mars, I noticed that there aren't any observation footprints at a latitude lower than -65° or higher than 65°. Why is this? Is there something I am not seeing? Is there a technical reason why these observations can't be done at the high latitudes?

[image]
Image centered near 65.698°, 328.230°E. Red ticks are HiRISE observations and yellow are HiRISE suggestions.

Disclaimer: I didn't look at the entire map, but I did look at a few different longitudes to see if the 65° limit was consistent across the planet.

Comment: Interesting! MRO's inclination is [93 degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter) so that's not an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HiRise routinely observes at high latitudes. In fact I can quickly find these examples:

- At $86.8^\circ$: https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/ESP_035295_2670
- At $82.2^\circ$: https://www.uahirise.org/ESP_027324_2625
- At $87.9^\circ$: https://www.uahirise.org/PSP_010623_2680
- At $85.8^\circ$: https://www.uahirise.org/PSP_010636_2660

You have a large gallery of high latitude examples here:
https://www.uahirise.org/science_themes/polar/index.php?page=159

So, the problem is not that MRO avoids the region but seems to be related to the online [HiWish Browser Map](https://www.uahirise.org/hiwish/browse) app. My guess is that the projection makes huge distortions on the image footprints and thus the software doesn't renders them (due to the code needing some enhancements to allow it or due to a conscious decision to avoid confusing visualizations of the rest of the footprints at high latitudes).

In the help section of the app you can read

> Near the poles, the elevation map will be better registered than the visible (and polar IR is not yet available through this interface).